# Matplotlib giving error "OverflowError: In draw_path: Exceeded cell block limit"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to render an image using `matplotlib` with 100000000 data points and it produces the error `OverflowError: In draw_path: Exceeded cell block limit`. Is there a limit in the amount of data points it can draw?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The problem is a hardcoded limit in the number of points in the backend Agg.

Try using:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000
```

or other large value.

You can find the issue and the solution proposed here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question/answer with a similar problem. It does the job but can you elaborate on your answer a bit. What does it do? What is the problem in the first place and what is the default value?

Comment: @Serinity. could you elaborate more on this answer, please. I have the same problem and I do not even know where to add that line.

Comment: @Herc01 `import matplotlib as mpl`

Comment: @Herc01 I added the line just before the call to plot() and it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 17):

The problem is a hardcoded limit in the number of points in the backend `Agg`.

It can be solved by `mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000`.

You can find the issue and the solution proposed here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907

Comment: True, since it was the same solution as the previous answer, but someone was asking for further explanation, I just gave the explanation.

Comment: Then you could have commented the accepted answer or suggested an edit to it.

Comment: The gain more points. Please don't abuse the system, please follow the rules.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem is because matplotlib uses default inline plotting, which means it connects the points. There's some limit to the points for that. But if you remove inline plotting, it might work. Try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', linestyle="None")
```

The 'ro' is for it to show red dots.