# OverflowError even with large agg.path.chunksize

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory

I'm working with the [NYC MVA data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Motor-Vehicle-Collisions-Crashes/h9gi-nx95). The dataset contains approximately 1.7 million records of crash data around NYC. I've created a new variable called `TOTAL PEDESTRIAN CASUALTIES`, and I'm trying to plot it against the hours of the day:

```
plt.plot(df['TOTAL PEDESTRIAN CASUALTIES'], df['CRASH TIME'].dt.hour)
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: Exceeded cell block limit (set 'agg.path.chunksize' rcparam)
```

As per [Serenity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37470899/7287543), I've tried to set the `rcParams`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 2_000_000
```

Yet even with a chunksize of 2 million, it is still too small. I've gone even bigger than that, with no effect. And apparently, I should be able to do [more with less](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841015/7287543).

How can I correct this issue to create this plot?

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my IDE with the setting `mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000` before my `plt.plot()` and it seemed to work.